# Efficient way of scaling hundreds of QGraphicItems

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

I have a zoomable `QGraphicsView` with scene that contains hundreds (and even thousands) of datapoints. The points are represented by `QGraphicsEllipseItem`s and collected into a `QGraphicsItemGroup`. When the view is zoomed in to I want datapoints to stay at a constant size (i.e., the distances between neigbouring points increase but the sizes stay the same). Right now I achieve this by running this code every time the user zooms in:

```py
#get all the QGraphicsEllipseItems that make up the QGraphicsItemGroup
children = graphics_item_group.childItems()
for c in children:
    #base_size_x and base_size_y are the sizes of the 
    #untrasformed ellipse (on the scene) when zoom factor is 1
    #New width and height are obtained from the original sizes and
    #the new zoom factors (h_scale, v_scale)
    new_width = base_size_x/h_scale
    new_height = base_size_y/v_scale

    #The top-left corner of the new rectangle for the item has to be recalculated 
    #when scaling in order to keep the center at a constant position
    #For this, the center of the item has to be stored first
    old_center_x = c.rect().center().x()
    old_center_y = c.rect().center().y()

    #New coordinates of the rectangle top left point are calculated
    new_topleft_x = old_center_x - new_width/2.
    new_topleft_y = old_center_y - new_height/2.

    #Finally a new rectangle is set for the ellipse
    c.setRect(new_topleft_x, new_topleft_y, new_width, new_height)
```

This code works. The problem is that it is quite slow (without the compensatory scaling zooming in/out works very smoothly). I tried turning off antialiasing for the view but it makes things look pretty ugly. Is there anything else that I can do to make  the processing/redrawing faster?

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of the QGraphicsItem:

```
    setFlag(ItemIgnoresTransformations);
```

When you zoom, the item will remain the same size, and you won't have to manually scale it.